# Need to return a variable from an ng-repeat button list

Tags: angularjs

I have a Json string that is made up of 'catID' and 'catName'.  So far, I have managed to create a list of buttons, labelled with each category.  I have been trying to return the catID when the user clicks on the button associated with the category.  It currently returns the $index, which is fine, but ideally the catID would allow me to pass the information onto the next stage of my coding.  I need the $index to activate the correct button.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
    <h4>Select Category</h4>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
         <li ng-repeat="categories in model" ng-class="{'active':rowIndex == $index }" ng-click="selectRow($index)">
         <a href="">{{categories.catID + " " + categories.catName}}</a>
         </li>
    </ul>
```

My Angular controller:

```
    app.controller("catBtnCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.selectRow = function (index) {
            if (index === $scope.rowIndex)
                $scope.rowIndex = -1;
            else
                $scope.rowIndex = index;
        };
    });
```

I have tried a couple of different methods, but they are drawing a blank.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What about this:
After you get the index in controller function, you can search for the right item details. 
Or you can pass 2 more values to the function and send them from html

**UPDATE**

```
 app.controller("catBtnCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.categoryID = null;
        $scope.categoryName = null;
        $scope.selectRow = function (index, id, name) {
            if (index === $scope.rowIndex)
                $scope.rowIndex = -1;
            else
                $scope.rowIndex = index;
            $scope.categoryID = id;
            $scope.categoryName = name;
            // next do some functions that retrieve the data that corresponds to these parameters
        };
    });
```

Select Category

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
     <li ng-repeat="categories in model" ng-class="{'active':rowIndex == $index }" ng-click="selectRow($index, categories.catID, categories.catName)">
     <a href="">{{categories.catID + " " + categories.catName}}</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of your hypothesis?

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate that. Helps me understand more about JavaScript too.

Comment: You welcome, I'm glad that I was able to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass whole item to function:

```
<li ng-repeat="categories in model" ng-class="{'active':rowIndex == $index }" ng-click="selectRow(categories, $index)">
  <a href="">{{categories.catID + " " + categories.catName}}</a>
</li>
```

But you'll need to change arguments to something like this:

```
$scope.selectRow = function (category, index) {}
```

Comment: That looks like what I am trying to do.  However, my knowledge in JavaScript/AngularJS is very small at the moment.  I feel there is more to it than just that. Though I may be wrong!